# Rest Framework/Library to use in TCL

Tags: rest, tcl

i am looking for a Tcl library to use, in order to build a rest program. I came across REST 1.0 package (http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/tcllib/rest/rest.html), but unfornetly it seems we can't download it no where ( i made many google search ect...).

Does anyone know how to download this package or where to get a rest library for tcl ?
PS: i am new to tcl

Thanks,

Comment: This package is part of tcllib. It's understandable even from the page, link to which you provided (`...Tcllib Table Of Contents | Tcllib Index...`) .

Comment: Thanks. But where can i download tcllib??And how to install it?? because when i do package require rest or packapage require tcllib i am getting "can't find package tcllib", "can't find package rest". And http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/ it says rest is not part of tcllib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are running ActiveTcl since you refer to the ActiveState documents above.

As I recall, it is distributed with a fairly minimal number of packages and you need to get the remaining packages as a seperate installation step.

Have you done the following?

```
teacup update
```

I'm running ActiveTcl 8.6 here, and I can `package require rest` just fine. You refer above to the documentation for version 8.5. I'm not sure whether that version has rest.

Good luck

Comment: You might need to run `teacup update` as root/Administrator (depending on OS and configuration).